# Can I set SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE) programmatically?

Tags: c#, oracle

As the title states, is it possible to set SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES programmatically with the Oracle.DataAccess DLL?

Comment: I think you can accomplish connections any way you need through the `OracleConnection` class. Why are you attempting to modify this? Maybe more background would help.

Comment: I have this issue and it's because one integration uses windows authentication and it throws ORA-01017 if it's set to None. The other integration uses Oracle integration and throws ORA-12640 if it's set to NTS or All

Answer (score 0):

@Adam - this needs to be set to NONE to prevent the classic invalid authorization / authentication method oracle provides to applications when they attempt (normally) the second connection to the machine.  Changing this value to none prevents this issue from occurring.

@user - this will be difficult depending on the location of the file as your application may need to be run as an administrator to run with the correct privileges to save the changes.